# how to center a widget inside a row when another image should have fixed distance (24) from the right edge?

Tags: flutter, dart

new in flutter

I'm having a row, and I'm trying to center an image inside of it, and another image that will be positioned exactly 24 points from the right of the screen.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
      height: 157,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 24,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          setDeviceIcon(),
          setArrow(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container setArrow() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.chevron_right,
          )),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
    );
  }
```

result should be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHhoW.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what it is exactly that you want and what you currently have (visually)?

Comment: Depends on how many children you've, is 3 fixed?

Comment: got only 2 children.

Comment: I can see three on current snippet, `Container`, `setDeviceIcon` and `setArrow`

Comment: added an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` on Container instead of providing margin on `setArrow`

```dart
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
  height: 157,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),// this the way you like
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 24,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Icon(Icons.device_hub),
      setArrow(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

```dart
  Container setArrow() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.chevron_right,
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: still won't go (the image is not in the center) unless i fix the black container width to be higher then 24. by the way, why the margin don't work?

Comment: Margin was paced of `setArrow`  and middle widget would be set on center, or I think now I needed to to provide padding on leftL24 too. Can you include an image pointing issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want those images to be in the center of the screen (or Row in this case), change the **mainAxisAlignment** attribute to:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

You want to center the elements inside the Row and then apply spacing between them with Margin, Padding or SizedBox.
The spaceBetween property, will force the children to align along all the Row's length applying space between them. Take a look at this:
[example of spacing in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TReUm.png)